# How to see if a chest been emptied by the player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to make a command that checks if a chest have been emptied by the player. If the chest is empty, I want to run this command:

```
/setblock x y z
```

Comment: I think that you will want to look at the /blockdata command.  If a chest is empty then the /blockdata command will show this.

Answer (score 2):

When you test for an empty list (e.g. `Items:[]`), it will only match if the target had an empty list as well.

The following only outputs if the chest had no items:

```
/testforblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A comparator will emit a redstone signal of strength directly proportional to how much "stuff" there is in an inventory it is facing away from. Simply put a camparator coming from the chest and send it into a NOT gate and use that to trigger the command block. When the chest is empty it will trigger the command but if there is at least 1 item in the chest it will output the signal and so not trigger the command block.

One thing to note is that the /setblock command may not trigger the block update so you could have your output also go to a piston after a delay to move a block top trigger the update.